# GWT NativeVerticalScrollbar CSS example

Tags: css, gwt, scrollbar

I just discovered the "CustomScrollPanel" and it seems to be a great piece of GWT. I also noticed that is is also possible to add a custom "NativeVerticalScrollbar".

However, I could not find out so far how to apply CSS to this object. I searched the web but did not find anything. In the source repository on github I discovered the file https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/master/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/NativeVerticalScrollbar.css however, it is empty.

So, can anybody please give an example what kind of css can be applied in order to style the scrollbar?

Answer (score 0):

You you familiar with `ClientBundle`? Take a look at the source code of the [CustomScrollPanel](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/master/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CustomScrollPanel.java) or the [NativeVerticalScrollbar](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/master/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/NativeVerticalScrollbar.java)

They both have a declarion of a `Resources` interface, all you need to do is to extend this interface and bundle a new CSS (or GSS) with your style.

This is the current `Resources` interface for the `NativeVerticalScrollbar`

```
  /**
   * A ClientBundle of resources used by this widget.
   */
  public interface Resources extends ClientBundle {
    /**
     * The styles used in this widget.
     */
    @Source(Style.DEFAULT_CSS)
    Style nativeVerticalScrollbarStyle();
  }
```

Create the CSS (or GSS) that you want, customize it away. It has to respect the `Style` Interface declaration (and the compiler fails if you don't)

```
  public interface MyNewResource extends com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.NativeVerticalScrollbar.Resource {
    /**
     * The styles used in this widget.
     */
    @Source("/PATH_TO_YOUR_CSS/newCss.css")
    com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.NativeVerticalScrollbar.Style nativeVerticalScrollbarStyle();
  }
```

Then when you create a new widget, just pass `MyNewResource` instance to the widget

```
 MyNewResource resources = GWT.create(MyNewResource.class)
 NativeVerticalScrollbar myScrollBar = new NativeVerticalScrollbar(resources);
```

Comment: Thanks. So, when I do this it becomes possible to style the scrollbars with CSS, right? That also means that Firefox can not be styled since it does not implement any CSS for styling the scrollbars?!

Comment: When you do this, you bundle your CSS file into the GWT application. If done correctly the GWT compiler will optimize, minify and obfuscate your CSS and will be applied to any browser you have. I mean for the CustomScrollPanel. The Native one uses.. the native scroll, Firefox doesn't provide a native way of styling it so it is left out.